# Vscode error squiggles show errors that are not there

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

For the past week intellisense reports errors that are not there, such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qra2T.png) or [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTFPw.png). In the first picture I don't have any "height" parameter declared in MDO class (i was assigning a value to it right on that line that the error is reported, but i've deleted it from everywhere and the error remained) and the second one speaks for itself. It doesn't seem to get fixed by reinstalling code or the C/C++ extension. Any suggestions on how to fix it ?

Comment: IntelliSense for C++ is notoriously unreliable. I usually fix problems with IntelliSense by switching off IntelliSense, because it's just annoying. (But you seem to not find "angry fruit salad" text annoying, so that's probably not a solution you like.)

Comment: @molbdnilo My main issue is that autocomplete is also not working properly, because I am used to fixing errors from what the compiler returns. I'll be sticking to CLion for now, which is a bummer, as I was enjoying working in VScode for 3+ years and this is the first time I've ever had an issue I could not fix.

Comment: It's probably an issue with the C++ language server. See if cpptools is crashing in the logs and report it here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=language-service.md&title=

Comment: Whenever you face an Intellisense non sense, recompile your code and it should be fixed.